# How can I stop the recursiveness of my Expression Tree? (C# / EF)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression-trees

I'm trying to get data out of my database using C# and Entity Framework.
My problem is that i have a recursive data model called "Template" which has a propperty called "Templates" which is a ICollection of "Template". In my query i have a `.Select(PageMappings.PageMapping)`. PageMapping is an Expression tree.
Eventually it goes to an Expresstion tree called "TemplateMapping". This Expression tree is recursive as you can see in the following code.

```cs
public static readonly Expression<Func<Data.Entities.Components.Layout.Template, Models.Components.Layout.Template>> TemplateMapping = 
    tp => new Models.Components.Layout.Template()
    {
        Title = tp.Title ?? string.Empty,
        Id = tp.HtmlId ?? string.Empty,
        Name = tp.Name ?? string.Empty,
        Alt = tp.Alt ?? string.Empty,
        //TODO Create mapping for the classes and styles
        Classes = tp.Classes.FormatStringToList(),
        Styles = tp.Styles.FormatStringToList(),

        Segments = (List<Segment>)new List<Segment>()
            .Concat(tp.Templates.AsQueryable().Select(TemplateMapping))
            .Concat(tp.Rows.AsQueryable().Select(RowMapping)).ToList()
    };
```

Somehow it keeps on calling TemplateMapping inside of TemplateMapping even if there is not a single "Template" inside the ICollection of "Templates".

I tried adding a `.Where(x => x.Templates != null)`. But this makes no diffrence.

How could i add a clause which ends the recursiveness of TemplateMapping when there are no "Template" inside of "Templates"?

Comment: EF needs to translate your expression into SQL, it does not matter if actually there are templates or not, it, as far as I understand, will just recursively will go into `Select(TemplateMapping)` and that's it. Not much can be done here except deleting recursive part and mapping data after fetching it form database.

Comment: Put an `AsEnumerable()` before the initial `.Select` and handle the mapping client side. Use `Func` instead of an `Expression` tree. Why are you using `AsQueryable` in your recursive call?

Comment: You have to build this expression by function, not static field. And you have to limit nesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions! It made me look at the problem from a diffrent perspective.

I tried mapping it to a diffrent object inside of the query. This worked up untill it got to the recursive part of of the code for "TemplateMapping".
I thought this would make the code good and clean. It looked clean, but it didn't work.

In my working version I wait for the data. Afterwhich i map it the way i want it to.

I wont be putting the working code here since its almost 300 lines.